# CSS Caching using RadStyleSheetManager

Tags: css, asp.net, caching, internet-explorer-8, telerik

I recently enabled the RadStyleSheetManager in my master pages using the following code:

```
<telerik:RadStyleSheetManager ID="RadStyleSheetManager1" runat="server" EnableStyleSheetCombine="true" />
```

In my web application, whose user base access it in ie8, the dynamically generated WebResource.axd files were getting so numerous that on a page with many telerik controls and grids, there were as many as 26 different WebResource.axd loaded. With ie8's restriction of only 31 style sheets active at any one time, this was causing some other external/internal styling to be lost since the WebResource.axd was bumping them out.

By using the RadStyleSheetManager, the WebResource.axd count is now always at 1 -- allowing all the user defined style sheets to be loaded without incident. However, I am now wondering about performance -- is the combined WebResource.axd cached, or is there any way to tell?

It seems that since there is only 1 http request rather than 26, performance should be increased, but I want to be sure that I am not shooting myself in the foot by requiring the WebResource.axd to be reloaded every time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as all your pages contain the same CSS files then the axd output will be the same and will be cached, yes.

But if you have some pages that use a different CSS file then a new axd will be generated for that page and will be served instead of the cached one.